# How to run Grafana with QuestDB

Tags: grafana, questdb

I've imported a demo dataset in QuestDB and I can query it successfully from the console. I'm using Grafana to build a dashboard to test visualization.

My QuestDB installation is running on port 9000 and I can import it without any issues:

```
curl -F data=@weather.csv http://localhost:9000/imp
```

I'm running the following query which is failing:

```
SELECT timestamp as time,
       avg(visMiles) AS average_visibility
FROM 'weather.csv'
WHERE $__timeFilter(timestamp)
SAMPLE BY $__interval
LIMIT 1000
```

The error I get is

```
pq: unknown function name: between(TIMESTAMP,STRING,STRING)
```

I'm using a dataset provided in their [examples](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/questdb.io/datasets/grafana_tutorial_dataset.tar.gz).

Answer (score 4):

QuestDB relies on a designated timestamp specified during table creation. This would not cause an error if one was provided with the curl request as a URL param, given a column named 'timestamp':

```sh
curl -F data=@weather.csv http://localhost:9000/imp?timestamp=timestamp
```

Another option is during a `SELECT` operation, a `timestamp()` function can specify one dynamically. If you've imported using curl and not set a designated timestamp, there are two options:

1. Modify your query to use `timestamp()` on the column you want to designate:

   ```sql
   SELECT timestamp as time,
          avg(visMiles) AS average_visibility
   FROM (‘weather.csv’ timestamp(timestamp))
   WHERE $__timeFilter(timestamp)
   SAMPLE BY $__interval
   LIMIT 1000
   ```
2. Create a new table which is a copy of your original dataset but designate a timestamp during creation. `ORDER BY` is used because the demo dataset has unordered timestamp entries:

   ```sql
   create table temp_table as (select * from ‘weather.csv’ order by timestamp) timestamp(timestamp);
   ```

   And instead of querying your original dataset, use the `temp_table`:

   ```sql
   SELECT timestamp as time,
     avg(visMiles) AS average_visibility
   FROM temp_table
   WHERE $__timeFilter(timestamp)
   SAMPLE BY $__interval
   LIMIT 1000
   ```

If you need more info on the use of designated timestamps, the QuestDB [concepts / timestamp docs](https://questdb.io/docs/concept/designated-timestamp) page has further details.

**Edit:** There are some more resources to with this topic such as a [guide for Grafana with QuestDB](http://localhost:3000/docs/third-party-tools/grafana) and [GitHub repo with docker-compose](https://github.com/questdb/questdb-slack-grafana-alerts).